# How to cancel tab change in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a `TabbedPage` and it contains a few `ContentPages`.

As I do some *edit* in one of the pages, *I intend to cancel both navigation back and changing the current tab page*.

Unfortunately, the only reasonable event that I found is `CurrentPageChanged` which happens **after the change of the current tab**.

Can I somehow cancel the change of the current tab page?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand based off the question - In the property for whatever you are setting when you edit the `Content Page` you could have a function that would cancel the change there.